# How to send Multiple notifications by Multiple AlarmManager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I need to make application which make different notification in different times 
I tried to make but only first one work. I don't know cause can you help me 
How can send more than one alarm manager in the same time

my mainactivity code

```
 AlarmManager  alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
    PendingIntent pending_intent;
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
    pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
    AlarmManager  alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
    PendingIntent pending_intent2;
    calendar2.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
    calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
     Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    myIntent2.putExtra("extra", "yes");
    pending_intent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 2, myIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager2.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent2);
    AlarmManager  alarmManager3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar3.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
    PendingIntent pending_intent3;
    calendar3.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
    calendar3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    final Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    myIntent3.putExtra("extra", "yes");
    pending_intent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 3, myIntent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager3.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar3.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent3);
    AlarmManager  alarmManager4 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar4.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
    PendingIntent pending_intent4;
    calendar4.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.MONTH,8);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
    calendar4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    final Intent myIntent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    myIntent4.putExtra("extra", "yes");
    pending_intent4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 4, myIntent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager4.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar4.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent4);
```

my AlarmReceiver BroadcastReceiver

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int monthsss = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyAccount", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        String first = pref.getString("first", null); // getting String
        String second = pref.getString("second", null); // getting String
        String third = pref.getString("third", null); // getting String
        String fourth = pref.getString("fourth", null); // getting String
        if (first !="done"){
            if (day== 1 && hour == 10 &&year ==2017 && min >0 && min  <2 && monthsss ==8   ){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, d1.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +"abanob.elkomos.girgisengagement"+ "/" + R.raw.noti1);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                     .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.td1))
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.d1)).setSound(sound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
                notificationManager.notify(100, mNotifyBuilder.build());

                editor.putString("first", "done"); // Storing string
                editor.commit(); // commit changes

            }
        }

        if (second !="done"){
            if (day== 3 && hour == 12 &&year ==2017 && min >0 && min  <2 && monthsss ==8  ){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, d2.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +"abanob.elkomos.girgisengagement"+ "/" + R.raw.noti1);


                NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        context)

                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.td2))
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.d2)).setSound(sound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
                notificationManager.notify(100, mNotifyBuilder.build());

                editor.putString("second", "done"); // Storing string
                editor.commit(); // commit changes

            }
        }
        if (third !="done"){
            if (day== 3 && hour == 17 &&year ==2017 && min >0 && min  <2  && monthsss ==8 ){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, d3.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +"abanob.elkomos.girgisengagement"+ "/" + R.raw.noti1);


                NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        context)

                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.td3))
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.d3)).setSound(sound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
                notificationManager.notify(100, mNotifyBuilder.build());

                editor.putString("third", "done"); // Storing string
                editor.commit(); // commit changes

            }
        }  if (fourth !="done"){
            if (day== 1 && hour == 20 &&year ==2017 && min >0 && min  <2 && monthsss ==8  ){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, d4.class);
                notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" +"abanob.elkomos.girgisengagement"+ "/" + R.raw.noti1);


                NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        context)

                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.td4))
                        .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.d4)).setSound(sound)
                        .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
                notificationManager.notify(100, mNotifyBuilder.build());

                editor.putString("fourth", "done"); // Storing string
                editor.commit(); // commit changes

            }
        }



    }
```

application work only in first alarm ,this meed that code of notification and broad cast is true

Comment: How are you testing these, exactly? I mean, `Calendar.AUGUST` is `7`, not `8`. All of those alarms are set for the beginning of next month. Are you changing the date/time on your device/emulator?

Comment: i change date and time of device ... first alarm and notification work successfully

Comment: Are you rebooting between date/time updates?

Comment: i close app and open it again

Comment: Are you dismissing the notifications between alarms? Pallavi  has a good point in their answer. You're using the same ID for each one, so if the previous one is still showing, the new `notify()` call is just going to update that one. Also, are you checking to see if the Receiver is actually running? Put a log print, or a breakpoint, or a `Toast`, etc. first thing in `onReceive()`. You're using a very convoluted way to determine which alarm is which, and those `if`s are kind of a cluster. Make sure that logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

For sending multiple notifications try this replace your line with

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE + (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

and add

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE = 101;
```

Comment: no  problem in notification ... problem in sending and recive alarm